# Replacing deck boards, frame got rained on

Tags: framing

Replacing my ground level deck boards and the framing lumber underneath just got soaked with rain. I don't know if the frame is PT or KD, but it is supposed to rain on and off the next few days so I am going to tarp it.

Will the frame be okay (sides were always exposed to rain, just not tops where boards were held in place?

Will tarping cause too much humidity when drying?

Comment: You can certainly cover the framing with tarp now, but as you might imagine building frameworks do regularly get drenched with rain during construction and it's normally no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your deck had gaps between the deck boards for drainage, in which case you would clearly see deterioration in the framing lumber if it wasn't treated.  Examine the deck framing for any deteriorated boards, or corroded hangers for replacement before placing the new deck surface.  Don't worry about it getting wet, even untreated lumber in house construction gets wet during construction with no adverse affects (it simply dries out as the structure is enclosed).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably fine. As long as they could drain successfully afterward and didn't sit waterlogged for long periods.